# Syntax error on token "(", delete this token

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm working on an app for my last year of A-Levels and I'm trying to make a colour averager. I can make the app take the picture and display it in an imageView but I can't seem to get the pixels from the image. I've tried using "imageViewName".getPixels or anything else .getPixels but the brackets after getPixels have the error "Syntax error on token "(", delete this token" and the same for the end bracket.

The error occurs here:

photoViewForCrop.getPixels(pixels[], x, y, imageWidth, imageHeight);

Which is quite close to the end of the code.

Here's my activity that takes the photo and saves it to the SD card, please ignore that it's called 'UploadPhotoActivity', not sure what I was thinking.

Imports or ints that aren't used in the code were added by my teacher when he was messing with it and not helping at all.

```
    package com.colours.javerager;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.Locale;

    import android.app.ActionBar;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.provider.MediaStore;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class UploadPhotoActivity extends Activity {

//Activity request codes
private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;

//directory for file names
private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "JAverager";

private Uri fileUri; //file url to store

private ImageView photoViewForCrop;
private Button takePhotoButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload_photo);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    //setupActionBar();
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    // hide the action bar
    actionBar.hide();

    photoViewForCrop = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photoViewForCrop);
    takePhotoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.takePhotoButton);

    /**
     * Capture image button click event
     */
    takePhotoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // capture picture
            captureImage();
        }
    });

    if (!isDeviceSupportCamera()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Sorry! Your device doesn't support camera",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // will close the app if the device does't have camera
        finish();
    }
}
//checks if device has a camera
private boolean isDeviceSupportCamera() {
    if (getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
            PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
        // this device has a camera
        return true;
    } else {
        // no camera on this device
        return false;
    }
}
private void captureImage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

    // start the image capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
}
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    // save file url in bundle as it will be null on screen orientation
    // changes
    outState.putParcelable("file_uri", fileUri);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    // get the file url
    fileUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("file_uri");
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // if the result is capturing Image
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // successfully captured the image
            // display it in image view
            previewCapturedImage();
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // user cancelled Image capture
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else {
            // failed to capture image
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Display image from a path to ImageView
 */
private void previewCapturedImage() {
    try { 
        photoViewForCrop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // bitmap factory
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

        // downsizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger
        // images
        options.inSampleSize = 2;

        final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(),
                options);

        photoViewForCrop.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
    return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}

/**
 * returning image 
 */
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

    // External sdcard location
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(
            Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d(IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME, "Oops! Failed create "
                    + IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
            Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "JAverager_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;



}

int imageWidth = 640;
int imageHeight = 480;
int[] pixels = new int[307200];
int x = 1;
int y = 1;
photoViewForCrop.getPixels(pixels[], x, y, imageWidth, imageHeight);
int pixelTotal= 307200;
int valuethispixel;
int currentBlue;
int currentRed;
int currentGreen;
int totalBlue = 0;
int totalRed = 0;
int totalGreen = 0;
int currentPixel = 1;
int tempNum;
int avRed;
int avGreen;
int avBlue;

{



while(1 < pixelTotal){
    tempNum = (Integer) pixels[currentPixel];
    currentBlue = Color.blue(tempNum);
    currentRed = Color.red(tempNum);
    currentGreen = Color.green(tempNum);
    totalBlue = totalBlue + currentBlue;
    totalRed = totalRed + currentRed;
    totalGreen = totalGreen + currentGreen;
    currentPixel = currentPixel + 1;
}

totalBlue = totalBlue / pixelTotal;
totalRed = totalRed / pixelTotal;
totalGreen = totalGreen / pixelTotal;

}
    };
```

Comment: Match your brackets. Check your syntax.

Comment: What's that piece of code doing outside a method? Or is it inside a method? Really hard to tell with the random indentation. Fix that and look again.

Answer (score 0):

`ImageView` does not implement the functionality you want.

Perhaps you should look at PixelGrabber ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/PixelGrabber.html

Answer (score 0):

everything after the getOutputMediaFile method is not inside a method, thats why your method call and after that the while loop definition won't work